# How to identify unit vectors with angle threshold quickly?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I am writing a program about computing geometry.

In this program, I need to identify unit vectors. (The word `identify` maybe not accurate)

i.e., writing a program to check whether a unit vector already exists.

This procedure is used when checking whether two polygons are on one plane. The first step is to check whether normal of two polygons are very close (angle < 1.0 degree).

> So, we can assume that
>
> 1. all vectors are unit vectors
> 2. vectors are random

For example, set the angle threshold to 1.0 degree. And we have 6 vectors.

```
(1,0,0)
(0,1,0)
(1,0,1e-8)  // in program, this will be normalized
(1,0,0)
(sin(45), cos(45),0)
(sin(44.9), cos(44.9),0)
```

then, the index of each vector is

```
0 1 0 0 2 2
```

i.e., the 1st / 3rd / 4th vectors are the same one because their angle is within 1.0 degree or just the same direction. angle between the 5th/6th vector is smaller than 1.0 degree.

Now, the problem comes, I have hundreds of thousands unit vectors to identify in different stages. This procedure costs about half of total time.

example code

```cpp
std::vector<Vector3d> unitVecs; // all unit vectors
                                // more than 100,000 unit vectors in real case

int getVectorID(const Vector3d& vec)
{
    for(int i=0; i<unitVecs.size(); ++i) {
        if(calcAngle(unitVecs[i], vec) <1.0) // 1.0 is angle degree threshold
            return i;
        /// alternatively, check with cos value
        if(unitVecs[i].dot(vec)>cos(1.0*RADIAN))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
int insertVector(const Vector3d& vec)
{
    int idx = getVectorID(vec);
    if(idx!=-1)    return idx;
    unitVecs.push_back(vec);
    return unitVecs.size()-1;
}
```

Does anyone have good ideas to accelerate this process ?

Comment: `calcAngle` presumably works by taking the dot product, normalizing, and computing the `acos`?  Since cosine is a decreasing function, you can instead compare the normalized dot product with the cosine of 1 degree, which you only have to compute once, saving the expensive `acos` on every iteration.

Comment: I did this in program, but there are hundreds of thousands unit vectors, this process still cost most time

Comment: Could you afford to check if a given vector is "roughly very close to being a unit vector", instead of precisely within 1 degree of a unit vector? Because in that case you would simply need to check that one value in the vector is large, and 3 are very small - computationally very straightforward!

Comment: I updated my question with "within 1 degree". But I am sorry that I didn't understand what you mean. Given a unit vector, how could I know to check which one without iterate all vectors?

Comment: Does `unitVecs` change frequently? Is comparison `vec` distinct for every getVectorID call?

Comment: Yes, MBo. All unit vectors are totally random. And to identify a new given unit vector, I have to call getVectorID(), i.e., compare with all saved vectors.

Comment: So... new example shows that you want to group (clusterize) vectors, and newly added vector should join to some cluster or make new own? I suspect that such algorithms exist in clustering/vector quantization/deep learning fields.

Comment: Also consider some kind of binary space partition. As example - unit sphere divided by  triangle mesh. Every vector refers to some cell, every cell stores list of vectors belonging to it.

Comment: yes, MBo. Do you know any existing solution (algorithm)?

Comment: Sadly no, it is just generalization of 2d rectangular grid approach.

Comment: You could key vectors by their spherical coordinates and then use threshold comparisons to the angular components of these. If memory is cheap, you could instead precompute unit vectors that subtend the unit sphere at your desired resolution. (I'm sure you can use symmetry relations to reduce the number of unit vectors you need to precompute, too.)

Comment: Hi, tehhowch. Could you give a detail solution? Or a url where I can find the way to key vectors ( or "encode" vector ) ?

Comment: Say you have a threshold of 1 degree and you have a 20 vectors densely packed between angles 30 and 32 degrees. How do you decide which ones to keep and which ones to remove in that situation? Are you happy with results that depend on the order of the input vectors?

Comment: yes,  Ranjeeth Mahankali . All vectors new added will be checked with all existing vectors. If no existing vectors close to new vector (<1 degree), the  new vector will be added at end of vector array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to accept vectors which are merely "very close to being unit vectors", as opposed to vectors which are strictly less than or equal to 1 degree from being a unit vector, you can simply check that for a given vector 3 values are very close to 0, and one value is very close to 1:

```
int valueCloseTo(float value, float trg, float epsilon=0.0001) {
  return abs(value) - trg <= epsilon;
}
int isRoughlyUnitVector(float x, float y, float z, float epsilon=0.0001) {
  
  // We can quickly return false if units don't add near 1
  // Could also consider multiplying `epsilon` x 3 here to account for accumulated error
  if (!valueCloseTo(x + y + z, 1, epsilon)) return false;
  
  // Now ensure that of x, y, and z, two are ~0 and one is ~1
  int numZero = 0;
  int numOne = 0;
  std::vector<float> vec{ x, y, z };
  for (float v : vec) {
    
    // Count another ~0 value
    if (valueCloseTo(v, 0, epsilon))      numZero++;
    
    // Count another ~1 value
    else if (valueCloseTo(v, 1, epsilon)) numOne++;
    
    // If any value isn't close to 0 or 1, (x,y,z) is not a unit vector
    else                                  return false;
    
    // False if we exceed 2 values near 0, and one value near 1
    if (numZero > 2 || numOne > 1) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Note that this method does not give any way to define a "maximum offset angle" (like 1deg in your question) - instead it lets us work with an `epsilon` value, which isn't an angle but rather a simple linear value. As `epsilon` increases vectors that are further from being unit vectors get accepted, but `epsilon` doesn't have an "angular" nature to it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But for vectors (sin(45), cos(45),0) and (sin(44.9), cos(44.9),0), this don't work.

Comment: Forgive me, my code wasn't tested (there were some glaring errors and some javascript snuck into my cpp). Can you try again with the updated code? It's 100% working now.

Comment: Thank you, Gershom. The code work for unit X/Y/Z vectors. but don't work for all other unit vectors. My question may mislead you, so I update the test cases.